# Conditional Codes to return 0,1,2,3 in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I would like to integrate my `Scapy` code with the Nagios monitoring tool and would want the results to return a 0,1,2,3.

The program works fine and acts as a passive listener to broadcast traffic and displays the IP address with the time intervals.

Can anyone help me with the code I could use to return these values, kindly find the code below.

Sorry I didn't include the code kindly find below:

```
    import sys
    import string
    import datetime
    import socket
    from datetime import datetime
    from scapy.all import *
    m_iface = "eth0"
    default_gw = "192.168.26.2"
    COUNTER_SLOTS = 5
    TIMEOUT = 20
    SCREEN_REFRESH = 15
    circular_counter = [0]*COUNTER_SLOTS
    session_start = {}
    session_stop = {}
    host_names = {}
    last_printed = 0

    host_names ["196.168.26.254"]=u'macbook'
    host_names ["192.167.26.237"]=u'testlocal'
    host_names ["192.168.26.238"]=u'xp1'
    host_names ["192.168.26.239"]=u'xp2'
    host_names ["192.168.26.2"]=u'default gateway'


    print "passive ping start"


    def arp_monitor_callback(pkt): 
    if ARP in pkt and pkt[ARP].op in (1,2): #who-has or is-at
    addr = pkt[ARP].psrc
    arp_counter(addr) 
return
    # circular buffer for statistics, 1 slot for 
    if UDP in pkt and IP in pkt:
    ipdata = pkt[IP]
    addr = ipdata.getlayer(IP).src
    arp_counter(addr)
    return

    def arp_counter(src):
    global last_printed
    tm = int(time.time())

    #print (pkt.psrc)
    #all_stats[src] = tm

    pos = src.find("192.168.26")
    if pos == -1:
    # print "wrong address"
    return

    if src in session_stop.keys():
    sess_stop = session_stop[src]
    if (tm - sess_stop)/60 > TIMEOUT:
    session_start[src] = tm   # start a new session
    session_stop[src] = tm   # start a new session
    else:
    session_stop[src] = tm   # start a new session

    else: # never saw the host
    session_start[src] = tm   # start a new session
    session_stop[src] = tm   # start a new session


    # print 
    if (tm - last_printed > SCREEN_REFRESH):
    print "-----------------------------------"
    last_printed = tm
    i = 1
    for k in sorted(session_start.keys(), cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(socket.inet_aton(x),                     socket.inet_aton(y))):
    if k in host_names.keys():
    hn = string.ljust(host_names[k], 40)
    else:
    hn = u'local_host_machine_ip'.ljust(40)

    last_hours = (tm - session_stop[k])/3600
    last_mins = ((tm - session_stop[k])/60) % 60

    s_start = (datetime.fromtimestamp(int(session_start[k])).strftime('%d/%m %H:%M'))
    s_stop = (datetime.fromtimestamp(int(session_stop[k])).strftime('%d/%m %H:%M'))

    pos = k.find("192.168.26")
    if pos != -1:
            print i, k,"\t", hn,"\t",last_hours,":",last_mins,"\t","                (",s_start,"==",s_stop,")",(session_stop[k] - session_start[k])/60
            i = i + 1

    #sys.stdout.flush()


    p = sniff(prn=arp_monitor_callback, store = 0)
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code!

Comment: Please **re**-post the relevant code. Just copy paste from editor, then select ALL the code and then press the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: Indentation is important in Python. Can you fix your code indentation please so we don't try to tell you about errors from indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities based on the limited explanation you have provided.

Python's `return` statement can be used to return a Python object or in this case, an integer.

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return

You'll have to use it inside a function. Since you haven't posted any code, I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want.

You can also use the `sys` module to return an exit status when you are done running a your Scapy code.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Example using `sys` -

```
import sys
from scapy.all import *

# Scapy magic

sys.exit(0) # exit with a code of 0
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve the problem. I just want the code to be integrated with nagios but need it to print out a 0 when the host is reachable and 3 when its not. It listens to UDP and ARP broadcast traffic and prints the ip address with the time intervals

Comment: Please be sure to re-upload your code so we can all take a good look at it.